# Azure Web app integration with External Git while deployment Fails with 401 error

Tags: azure, deployment

When source code is committed to Git Hub , it should automatically deploy to Azure app service when the option in Azure integration is selected as "External Git" . But it fails with 401 error. Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good troubleshooting guide for Azure Web App deployments.

https://benperk.github.io/waws/2015/2015-08-troubleshooting-web-app-deployment-issues-when-using-git-github.html